# Angular refuses to set my background

Tags: angular, background-image, ng-style

I'm trying to set the background of my page. Whatever I try, it doesn't load.

This is my page:

```
<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getUrl()}">
  <div class="col-4 justify-content-end">
    <button (click)="onLogin()" class="btn btn-success">login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the ts file:

```
/*
*  Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
*  See LICENSE in the source repository root for complete license information.
*/

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  onLogin() {
    this.authService.login();
  }

  getUrl() {
    return "url('https://www.pxl.be/Assets/website/pxl_algemeen/afbeeldingen/pxl_beeld_geselecteerd.jpg')";
  }
}
```

Anybody got an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you you have exactly when you look at the background-image CSS property for the div in chrome's debugger?

Comment: The background image is set with the correct url...

Comment: Maybe you've got some other css rule hiding it then?  DId you see @Vivek Doshi's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working as expected only issue over here here is , `height` of the div and you can also use `background-size`

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bg-image)**

Answer (score 1):

Angular will not let you inject your app with vulnerabilities by accident. You need to sanitize that CSS first:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
getUrl() {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(url('https://www.pxl.be/Assets/website/pxl_algemeen/afbeeldingen/pxl_beeld_geselecteerd.jpg')";
}
```